# How does Signal protocol work? Message queue is somehow disappeared after requested?

Tags: signal

Signal claims they only know when users created their account and when users last connected to the server, but what about the message queue waiting for users devices to come online?

I don't know how Signal Protocol works, but it must be tied to users' accounts in some way. Then Signal knows the message queue is encrypted but isn't it still data that can be handed over?

Comment: This question makes no sense. There's a lot here that doesn't tie together. Are you asking how Signal servers know how to deliver queued messages?

Comment: " Signal queues end-to-end encrypted messages on its servers for delivery to devices that are temporarily offline" https://signal.org/legal/#privacy-policy

Comment: if Signal servers does have queued messages for its users, how can Signal’s subpoena responses does not include any. (I believed Signal, so I have to assume it has someway to disappear it)

Comment: If a Signal user received one or more messages since the last time his/her device connected to Signal's server - then yes, these messages would be queued on Signal's servers.  Sure, Signal could hand these over in response to a subpoena, but these queued messages are encrypted and Signal does not have the key needed to decrypt them.